# Where are the ECC memory error counters stored?

Tags: memory, ecc

Where are the ECC memory error counters stored: on the DIMM itself, the motherboard, or the host's disk?

I'm using memtest86+, but it seems that it doesn't recognize ECC on my system, so if correctable errors occur, memtest86+ just won't see them. I'd like to know if they'd still show up in, on Linux, `/sys/devices/system/edac`, which of course they won't, if storing the error counts is the OS's responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are counted by the OS only. The counters are indeed transient but if you reboot and let the system run for a while and it doesn't trigger the errors again you should be ok. Ofcourse, you need to run a load that touches the memory to generate any error counts.